# Postinstallscript fails to insert child records

Tags: apex, managed-package, error, postinstall

I have a post install script that executes after the package has been installed and it worked perfectly. But recently it had to be changed to include some dummy data as an example. So I added the code to add that data, but it never appeared in my test orgs after installation of the package(I uninstalled the old one and installed the new one, so it's not an update).

For debugging I also edited the `try - catch` block:

```
try {
    insert myList;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailTobeSent = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    List<String> listEmailMembers = new List<String>();
    listEmailMembers.add('myEm@il.here');
    emailTobeSent.setToAddresses(listEmailMembers);
    emailTobeSent.setSubject('Post install exception');
    emailTobeSent.setHtmlBody('Message : ' + ex.getMessage() + '\nLine no : ' + ex.getLineNumber() + '\ngetStackTraceString: ' + ex.getStackTraceString() + '\nCause: ' + ex.getCause());
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r1 = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {emailTobeSent});
}
```

And after installing a package with this code, I got the following mail:

> Message : Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: [] Line no : 1267 getStackTraceString: Class.MySuperAwesomePackageName.PostInstallClass.onInstall: line 1267, column 1 Cause: null

That line 1267 is `insert myList;`

I'm sure that the code works, if I put it in some method and then call this method from *Execute Anonymus* window it works perfectly and inserts all the records that I need, but if it is executed from post install script it fails.

I did some research, but the only thing that I could find was that *Salesforce* uses some special **ghost user** for during installation and it appears that this user does not have enough privileges for that custom object.

Is there some workaround so that I can insert these records?

Comment: Does PostInstallClass use the 'with sharing' keyword?

Comment: @DavinC no, it is declared as `global without sharing class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler`

Comment: According to https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=apex_post_install_script_intro.htm&language=en_US you should be able to call installerId(), maybe it would be worth checking user access of this user against the object you're trying to insert records into?

Comment: Also here is a good article https://zachelrath.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/migrate-your-post-install-and-uninstall-tasks-to-apex-install-scripts/

Comment: Similar question: [INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY when setting custom field on a Task](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/66055/102)

Comment: Are there any triggers or similar on the records that you are inserting?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue inserting PermissionSetAssignment records.  It only seems to fail in some sandboxes.